# console's window which started from batch file does not show whole process

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, bots

I use batch files to run some python bots from several folders. So these bots work by windows console cmd.exe and need to be always running as a process. In batch files I marked that running windows should be little size

```
mode 50, 10
cd /d C:/bots 2.0/14 & python config.py
```

And the problem with that is that whole processes in that windows with actions and erorrs does not show.

I mean that the place before date in that window have so many infomation and scroll just dissapeared.

[image]

How can we fix that little problem?

Comment: The line `cd /d C:/bots 2.0/14 & python config.py` should read `cd /d "C:\bots 2.0\14" && python config.py`. Windows uses a back slash for its directory separator, and depending upon the OS/FileSystem, `CD` does not automatically know when spaces are included in the directory location. The ampersand you've used is a lazy way, especially in a batch file, of not using the next line. However, in this case my assumption is that you do not wish to run your python script, if the change of directory failed, therefore I have replaced it with the if successful, `&&`, condition instead.

Comment: you are sure my friend, thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

Open command-prompt, right-click the bar on the top and go to properties. There is an option to enable linewrap. The lines will wrap back around so this should solve your problem.